# how to send Notification to mobile device using PHP cURL and FCM?

Tags: php, curl, push-notification

how to send Notification to mobile device using PHP cURL and FCM?

```
$ch = curl_init(); //init
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');//Fire URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);//send Headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch); //.json_encode($fields);
return $result;
curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run the above code? _Side note:_ You should close the curl handler before the `return` statement. Any code that comes after a return doesn't get executed.

Comment: You can use following code you will need API_KEY and device_token .The link is [link](https://gist.github.com/MohammadaliMirhamed/7384b741a5c979eb13633dc6ea1269ce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$to - Device ID

$title - Notification Title

$message - Notification Message

$img - Full image link

$datapayload - Array of your custom value.

**Usage:**

**sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img, $datapayload = "");**

With Demo Values :

sendnotification("Device_ID","Test Notification","Test Message","https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png",array("ID"=>1));

```
function sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img = "", $datapayload = ""){
$msg = urlencode($message);
$data = array(
    'title'=>$title,
    'sound' => "default",
    'msg'=>$msg,
    'data'=>$datapayload,
    'body'=>$message,
    'color' => "#79bc64"
);
if($img){
    $data["image"] = $img;
    $data["style"] = "picture";
    $data["picture"] = $img;
}
$fields = array(
    'to'=>$to,
    'notification'=>$data,
    'data'=>$datapayload,
    "priority" => "high",
);
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key=GOOGLE_API_KEY',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
return $result;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrNotificationMessage =   array(
                                'title'=>'Test',
                                'text'=>"Testing Notification",
                                'sound' => "mySound",
                                'priority'=>"high"                              
                            );

$extraData  =   array(
                    'any_extra_data'    =>"any data"
                );
$deviceToken    =   "User device FCM token id";
$ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    $header=array('Content-Type: application/json',
        "Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"notification\": ".json_encode($notificationMessage).", \"data\":" . json_encode($extraData) . ", \"to\" : ".json_encode($deviceToken)."}");

    $result =   curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        //log_message("DEBUG", 'Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    else{
        $result =   json_decode($result);
        if($result->success ===1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```